# Correlation between variables under the for loop

Tags: r

I have an issue that is shown below. I tried to solve it but was not successful. I have a dataframe df1. I need to make a table of correlation between the variables within a for loop. Reason being I do not want to make the code look long and complicated.

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), b = c(3, 5, 7, 4, 3), c = c(3, 
6, 8, 1, 2), d = c(5, 3, 1, 3, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -5L))
```

I tried with the below code using 2 for loops

```
  fv <- as.data.frame(combn(names(df1),2,paste, collapse="&"))
  colnames(fv) <- "ColA"
  fv$ColB <- sapply(strsplit(fv$ColA,"\\&"),'[',1)
  fv$ColC <- sapply(strsplit(fv$ColA,"\\&"),'[',2)
  asd <- list() 
  for (i in fv$ColB) {
  for (j in fv$ColC) {
    asd[i,j] <- as.data.frame(cor(df1[,i],df1[,j]))}}
```

May I know what wrong I am doing

Comment: Wouldn't `out <- cor(df1); out[upper.tri(out, diag = FALSE)]` works for you

Comment: Thanks, But I need to know what are the 2 variables for under this correlation? Cna we? For example cor(df1$a,df1$b) is -0.09449112 and so on

Comment: If you check the `out`, the column and row names correspond to the particular correlation

Comment: if we really need the `names`, then do a `melt` `library(reshape2); melt(out)` and it would give the two columns for column name and row names corresponding to the value

Comment: Perfect but May I know what out[upper.tri(out, diag = FALSE)] is doing here. ?

Comment: It is because `cor(df1)` gives a matrix of values with the same values repeated in the mirror image in lower triangle

Answer (score 1):

We can apply `cor` directly on the `data.frame` and convert to 'long' format with `melt`.  As the values in the lower triangular part is the mirror values of those in the upper triangular part, either one of these can be assigned to `NA` and then do the `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
out[lower.tri(out, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
melt(out, na.rm = TRUE)
```